# Declaring a function level static variable inside an if block that is never hit

Tags: c

My understanding about static variables declared inside a function is:

1. If no initial value is specified, the static variable will reside in `.bss`, otherwise in `.data`
2. The memory for statics are allocated along with globals - i.e., well before the execution enters `main`

   - are these two assumptions correct **?**
3. When the execution hits the function for the first time, statics are initialized to the user specified value (or zero in case no initial value is specified).
4. ...and they retain their values across subsequent invocations of the function

But what if I declare my static variable inside an `if` block? I assume my third point should be updated to *"when the execution hits the line where the static variable is declared, they're initialized to ... "* - am I right **?**

Now, what if the `if` block in which they're declared is never hit (and the compiler is able to figure this out) - I understand that the variable will never be initialized; but does any memory get allocated for that variable?

I wrote two functions to try to figure out what's happening:

```
#include <stdio.h>

void foo()
{
    static foo_var_out;
    if(0){
        static foo_var_in_0;
        printf("%d %d\n", foo_var_in_0);
    } else {
        static foo_var_in_1;
        printf("%d %d\n", foo_var_in_1);
    }   
}

static void bar(int flag)
{
    static bar_var_out;
    if(flag){
        static bar_var_in_0;
        printf("%d %d\n", bar_var_in_0);
    } else {
        static bar_var_in_1;
        printf("%d %d\n", bar_var_in_1);
    }   
}

int main()
{
    foo();
    bar(0);
}
```

And I took the object dump:

```
$ gcc -o main main.c
$ objdump -t main | grep var
45:080495c0 l     O .bss    00000004              foo_var_in_1.1779
46:080495c4 l     O .bss    00000004              foo_var_out.1777
47:080495c8 l     O .bss    00000004              bar_var_in_1.1787
48:080495cc l     O .bss    00000004              bar_var_in_0.1786
49:080495d0 l     O .bss    00000004              bar_var_out.1785
```

From the output it looks like `foo_var_in_0` was not created at all (presumably because  it is inside an explicit `if(0)`), whereas `bar_var_in_0` was created (as it is possible for the caller to pass a non-zero value - although the only caller is explicitly passing zero).

I guess my question is: is it correct to assume that no memory was allocated for the variable `foo_var_in_0` at all? I am asking about this specific case; am I reading the objdump correctly - or should I be doing something more to verify if the variable will take some memory while the program is ran?

In other words, if the line that declares a function level static variable is never hit, is the variable actually declared at all?

If it will not be created at all, is this according to the C standard (less likely), or a compile time optimization and at what level - how do I turn it ON/OFF (in gcc 4.1.1)?

I understand that one int is not a big deal to care about, but I am more interested in how it works; also, what if the variable was a big array of size, say 5000 elements of a 10 byte struct?

Comment: Both are created for me: http://pastebin.com/6cRbHWMJ (mingw gcc 4.5.1)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> is it correct to assume that no memory was allocated for the variable foo_var_in_0 at all?

No, I don't think it would be correct to assume that. As far as I know, optimizations like this are not part of the standard.

If you know for a fact that you compiler does this and you want to assume it, go ahead.  If you write anything that needs this to be the case, you might want to write a post-build test to make sure that it happened.

Probably, what you are seeing is a side-effect of the compiler just pruning out some code that it knew would never run.  Meaning, it's not specifically looking to remove statics, but it did remove an entire branch, so any code in it just got removed as well.

Comment: Based on the objdump data in this specific case (I understand that it isn't wise to rely on that - but to confirm that I'm reading objdump correctly), I can safely assume that no space was set aside for that variable - is that correct? Or is there something else I need to do to verify if the variable will its memory while running?

Comment: I believe that you read objdump correctly and that the static was never allocated.  I think in this case, for this compiler, on this compilation, you can assume that no space was set aside.  You can not assume that to be the case for the future unless you keep verifying it.

Comment: Thanks - and I get the message; am not gonna rely on this behavior :)

Comment: Is it possible to get control over this optimization - does it correspond to any particular gcc optimization level?

Comment: If you care this much about the machine code, you should be writing assembly.  I'm not sure why you need to do this, but C was not designed for this kind of pinpoint control of the executable.  The design goals of C are incompatible with this need.

Comment: I was just trying to see if it is possible to turn it off using a compiler flag - just out of curiosity/academic interest if you will.

Answer (score 2):

The C standard does not prescribe where to place variables and stuff. It just prescribes that a conforming implementation shall have equivalent behaviour (to a reference behaviour which is specified by the standard), where "equivalent" is also defined by the standard.

So the simple answer is that it is an optimization, and how to turn it on/off depends on the particular compiler.

An implementation that does interprocedural analysis would probably be able to get rid of `bar_var_in_0` as well.

Comment: That makes more sense - it is plain removal of unreached code - nothing specific to static.

Answer (score 2):

Just to add to the correct answers from the others. Your assumptions about initialization of `static` variables are not correct.

- Variables with static storage are
  always initialized. Either explicitly
  if you provide an initializer or
  implicitly from `0`.
- The initializer for such a variable
  must always be a compile time
  constant expression. So the value is
  computed at compile time and written
  directly into the object. (Well if it
  is all zero, some systems have tricks
  / special sections that avoid an
  explicit storage of the variable in
  the object file.)
- So, no, there will be no initializer
  statement run when the variable is
  accessed the first time (how would
  the system know, by the value of
  another static variable?) but whenever
  you start the program the variable is
  already initialized.

Comment: Thank you - I was not aware that the initializer must be a compile time constant.